# Confide user not staying logged into admin after page reload

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I followed the Zizaco tutorials on github for Confide and it seems that I have done everything correctly as it goes to the admin page after I log in.  The problem is when I refresh the page it redirects back to the login page.  Am I missing something or is this a bug?  I thought it might be the way I am routing but cant seem to figure this out as I am new to Confide.

### **SEE BELOW**

**routes.php**

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/






// Dashboard route 
Route::get('/admin', function(){ 
    return View::make('site.pages.admin.index'); 
}); 

// Only authenticated users will be able to access routes that begins with
// 'admin'. Ex: 'admin/posts', 'admin/categories'.
Route::when('admin*', 'auth');





//

// Confide routes
Route::get('users/create', 'UsersController@create');
Route::post('users', 'UsersController@store');
Route::get('users/login', 'UsersController@login');
Route::post('users/login', 'UsersController@doLogin');
Route::get('users/confirm/{code}', 'UsersController@confirm');
Route::get('users/forgot_password', 'UsersController@forgotPassword');
Route::post('users/forgot_password', 'UsersController@doForgotPassword');
Route::get('users/reset_password/{token}', 'UsersController@resetPassword');
Route::post('users/reset_password', 'UsersController@doResetPassword');
Route::get('users/logout', 'UsersController@logout');
```

**filters.php**

```
    <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application & Route Filters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Below you will find the "before" and "after" events for the application
| which may be used to do any work before or after a request into your
| application. Here you may also register your custom route filters.
|
*/

App::before(function($request)
{
    //
});


App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    //
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Filters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following filters are used to verify that the user of the current
| session is logged into this application. The "basic" filter easily
| integrates HTTP Basic authentication for quick, simple checking.
|
*/

Route::filter('auth', function () {
    // If the user is not logged in
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        return Redirect::guest('users/login');
    }
});

// Only authenticated users will be able to access routes that begins with
// 'admin'. Ex: 'admin/posts', 'admin/categories'.
Route::when('/admin', 'auth');


Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    return Auth::basic();
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Guest Filter
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The "guest" filter is the counterpart of the authentication filters as
| it simply checks that the current user is not logged in. A redirect
| response will be issued if they are, which you may freely change.
|
*/

Route::filter('guest', function()
{
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/');
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CSRF Protection Filter
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The CSRF filter is responsible for protecting your application against
| cross-site request forgery attacks. If this special token in a user
| session does not match the one given in this request, we'll bail.
|
*/

Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Session::token() !== Input::get('_token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

**UserController.php**

```
<?php



/**
 * UsersController Class
 *
 * Implements actions regarding user management
 */
class UsersController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Displays the form for account creation
     *
     * @return  Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return View::make('users.signup');
    }

    /**
     * Stores new account
     *
     * @return  Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        $repo = App::make('UserRepository');
        $user = $repo->signup(Input::all());

        if ($user->id) {
            if (Config::get('confide::signup_email')) {
                Mail::queueOn(
                    Config::get('confide::email_queue'),
                    Config::get('confide::email_account_confirmation'),
                    compact('user'),
                    function ($message) use ($user) {
                        $message
                            ->to($user->email, $user->username)
                            ->subject(Lang::get('confide::confide.email.account_confirmation.subject'));
                    }
                );
            }

            return Redirect::action('UsersController@login')
                ->with('notice', Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.account_created'));
        } else {
            $error = $user->errors()->all(':message');

            return Redirect::action('UsersController@create')
                ->withInput(Input::except('password'))
                ->with('error', $error);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays the login form
     *
     * @return  Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if (Confide::user()) {
            return Redirect::to('/admin');
        } else {
            return View::make(Config::get('confide::login_form'));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to do login
     *
     * @return  Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function doLogin()
    {
        $repo = App::make('UserRepository');
        $input = Input::all();

        if ($repo->login($input)) {
            return Redirect::intended('/admin');
        } else {
            if ($repo->isThrottled($input)) {
                $err_msg = Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.too_many_attempts');
            } elseif ($repo->existsButNotConfirmed($input)) {
                $err_msg = Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.not_confirmed');
            } else {
                $err_msg = Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.wrong_credentials');
            }

            return Redirect::action('UsersController@login')
                ->withInput(Input::except('password'))
                ->with('error', $err_msg);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to confirm account with code
     *
     * @param  string $code
     *
     * @return  Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function confirm($code)
    {
        if (Confide::confirm($code)) {
            $notice_msg = Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.confirmation');
            return Redirect::action('UsersController@login')
                ->with('notice', $notice_msg);
        } else {
            $error_msg = Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.wrong_confirmation');
            return Redirect::action('UsersController@login')
                ->with('error', $error_msg);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays the forgot password form
     *
     * @return  Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function forgotPassword()
    {
        return View::make(Config::get('confide::forgot_password_form'));
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to send change password link to the given email
     *
     * @return  Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function doForgotPassword()
    {
        if (Confide::forgotPassword(Input::get('email'))) {
            $notice_msg = Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.password_forgot');
            return Redirect::action('UsersController@login')
                ->with('notice', $notice_msg);
        } else {
            $error_msg = Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.wrong_password_forgot');
            return Redirect::action('UsersController@doForgotPassword')
                ->withInput()
                ->with('error', $error_msg);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows the change password form with the given token
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return  Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function resetPassword($token)
    {
        return View::make(Config::get('confide::reset_password_form'))
                ->with('token', $token);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt change password of the user
     *
     * @return  Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function doResetPassword()
    {
        $repo = App::make('UserRepository');
        $input = array(
            'token'                 =>Input::get('token'),
            'password'              =>Input::get('password'),
            'password_confirmation' =>Input::get('password_confirmation'),
        );

        // By passing an array with the token, password and confirmation
        if ($repo->resetPassword($input)) {
            $notice_msg = Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.password_reset');
            return Redirect::action('UsersController@login')
                ->with('notice', $notice_msg);
        } else {
            $error_msg = Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.wrong_password_reset');
            return Redirect::action('UsersController@resetPassword', array('token'=>$input['token']))
                ->withInput()
                ->with('error', $error_msg);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out of the application.
     *
     * @return  Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        Confide::logout();

        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a session issue to me. What session driver are you using? Try a different one...

Comment: I am current using the file driver...I just tried others but no go...

Comment: try the database session driver. I had similar session issues with the file driver.